# Implementation of time in Zynq

Tags: c, time.h, zynq

I'm trying to do a simple STANDALONE application for Zynq. I want to use the 'time.h' to manipulate date/time. I know that there is no hardware implementation on a stanalone BSP, but I want to wire it up on my own. 
During compilation, when I call 'time(NULL)' I get a error, that there is no implementation of '_gettimeofday()'. I've found it in  and implemented it according to the function definition, so that the errors disappear and everything looks ok, but when I run my project on hardware, I see only zeroes from time().
Can anybody help?

Regards,
G2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've done some research, and found this [link](http://zedboard.org/content/execution-time-measurement). This is almost what I'v been searching, but instead of '_times()' I needed '_gettimeofday()' and this is my implementation:

```
int _gettimeofday(struct timeval *__p, void *__tz)
{
    __p->tv_sec = (systemUsCounter / 1000000);
    __p->tv_usec = systemUsCounter;
    return 0;
}
```

I left the '__tz' pointer with no chainges.
So this is basicly how to utilize 'time.h' in a standalone application on Zynq.